# Why is this external script being loaded directly after an internal script?

Tags: javascript

Why should I link an external script write after an internal script [as following example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_file)

Can anyone tell me why I should use it like this and why it doesn't display anything before the call to the external script ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>
<script>
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
        arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

<script src="myTutorials.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling `myFunction` anywhere. Can you post that code as well?

Comment: 1) why not? 2) because you're just DEFINING a function. The function isn't actually CALLED, so it doesn't do anything.